# Adding an emoji to an embed message

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been looking for a good few hours, and I've found nothing on why this isn't working for me.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
  name = "tickets"
  category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
  guild = ctx.message.guild
  ticket_id = randint(0, 100)
  ticket_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"ticket-0{ticket_id}", category=category)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Tickets", description="Support will be with you shortly.\nTo close this ticket, react with :lock:.")
  await ticket_channel.send(embed=embed)
  await bot.add_reaction(embed, emoji=":lock:")
  while True:
    await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji="\N{LOCK}", message=embed)
    await bot.delete_channel(ticket_channel)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Ignoring exception in command ticket:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 40, in ticket
    await bot.add_reaction(embed, emoji=":lock:")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

Any help is resolving this issue, is much appreciated.

Comment: `add_reaction` is a method of the `Message` class, not `Bot`.  `Embed` does not subclass `Message`.  To get the `Message` object associated with the `Embed` you need to store the return value of `channel.send(embed=...)`

Comment: Oh, I'm really stupid. I forgot about that. I was trying to add the reaction to the actual embed, not the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_reaction` is a method of the `Message` class, not `Bot`.  `Embed` does not subclass `Message`.  To get the `Message` object associated with the `Embed` you need to store the return value of `channel.send(embed=...)`

```py
message = await ticket_channel.send(embed=embed)
await message.add_reaction('\N{LOCK}')
```